# If nested Optional is empty, return another optional

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, option-type

How looks my Car model

```
class Car {
   // some fields here
   Optional<Engine> engine;
}
```

How i can make it in few steps:

```
    public Optional<Engine> checkEngine (Optional<Car> car) {
        Optional<Engine> engine = car
                .flatMap(Car::getEngine)
        if (engine.isPresent()) {
            return engine;
        }
        return Optional.of(new Engine("At the moment car don't have the engine"));
    }
```

I would like to do it in 1 optional exspression:

```
    public Optional<Engine> checkEngine (Optional<Car> car) {
        return car
                .flatMap(Car::getEngine)
                .orElse(Optional.of(new Car("At the moment car don't have the engine")));
    }
```

But it does not work, intelij idea says that requered type is Engine, but i am returning optional of Engine. But the method is Optional

Comment: Just insert a `map(Optional::of)` before the `orElse`. It is quite clumsy, but the API for this was introduced in later versions of java (https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/16/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)).

Comment: @CoronA it works. Could you move it to answers? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to return an `Optional` when it can never be empty? It’s weird, to return an `Engine` when there is none or even when there’s no car at all, just to require the receiver to read the engine’s string to find out that there is none. Your second snippet is even weirder, as it attempt to return a `new Car(…)` where an engine is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possibiltiy to join two Optionals with an Optional result was introduced in a Java version later than 8 ([https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/16/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/16/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier))).

In Java 8 you have to work around this problem, e.g.

```
public Optional<Engine> checkEngine (Optional<Car> car) {
  return car
    .flatMap(Car::getEngine)
    .map(Optional::of)
    .orElse(Optional.of(new Engine("At the moment car doesn't have the engine")));
}
```

using the Java 9 `or()` it would look like:

```
public Optional<Engine> checkEngine (Optional<Car> car) {
  return car
    .flatMap(Car::getEngine)
    .or(() -> Optional.of(new Engine("At the moment car don't have the engine")));
}
```

**More detail why using `or` can make sense:**

This techniques seems very complicated on the first view - and in fact - just for this example I would prefer a solution just without returning an optional;

Yet this technique is not senseless in general, it is quite helpful if we have a set of fallback functions, each returning an optional, e.g.

```
public Optional<Engine> checkEngine (Optional<Car> car) {
  return car
    .flatMap(Car::getEngine)
    .or(this::fallback1) //only call this expensive method as fallback
    .or(this::fallback2); //only call this expensive method as fallback
}

public Optional<Engine> fallback1() {
  //some code computing a fallback, but can fail and then returns empty
}

public Optional<Engine> fallback2() {
  //some code computing a fallback, but can fail and then returns empty
}
```

Another reason why to use this pattern is that we cannot assume that the method does not return real Optionals before the final return, e.g.

```
public Optional<Engine> checkEngine (Optional<Car> car) {
  if (isInvalid()) {
    return Optional.empty(); // this is a true error
  }
  // other code
  return car
    .flatMap(Car::getEngine)
    .or(() -> Optional.of(new Engine("At the moment car don't have the engine"))); // it is not an error if car is empty, because there is a valid default
}
```

Comment: Or `return Optional.of(car.flatMap(Car::getEngine).orElse(new Car("At the moment car don't have the engine")));` Even using the new `or` is not simpler. But the entire approach is strange anyway. Where’s the sense in returning a non-empty optional for an absent value…

Comment: Of course you are right, if the method is such simple as it is now and if the API is not public and not already used. But if we view this just as an example, there are several reasons why one should do it this way. I added some explanatory examples.

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct, you are passing wrong types:

```
public Optional<Engine> checkEngine (Optional<Car> car) {
    return car
            .flatMap(Car::getEngine)
            .orElse(Optional.of(new Car("At the moment car don't have the engine")));
}
```

1. `car` is `Optional<Car>`
2. I suppose that `Car::getEngine` is `Optional<Engine>`
3. [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) take a `Function<? super T, Optional<U>>` where `T` is the bound type of `Optional`, here: `Car`, and U the result: here `Engine`. It returns an `Optional<U>`.
4. [`orElse(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) return an already computed result. Since we are after flatMap, `T` is equals to `Engine`.

**Note:** I linked to the Javadoc of Java 8.

So the expected value in `orElse` is an `Engine`.

You should simply stop after `flatMap`:

```
public Optional<Engine> checkEngine (Optional<Car> car) {
    return car.flatMap(Car::getEngine);
}
```

And I don't think you should return an "invalid" `Engine` like you tried to do: you would never be able to distinguish from case where the Engine is missing and those from where it is present.

You should throw:

```
public Engine checkEngine (Optional<Car> car) {
    return car.flatMap(Car::getEngine)
              .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("no engine"));
}
```

Notice I changed the result from `Optional<Engine>` to `Engine`.

Comment: ok, in this case oprional will give me Engine of car, if it is present.
But also, i would change this logic a little bit: if engine is not present -> return another optinal of engine. I didn't see, that i wrote engine in model without optional

Comment: There is no need to return an `Optional<Engine>`: simply returns an `Engine`. This is useless at this point and definitively not the correct usage of `Optional`.